# XZ Header and Footer

Tags: bash, cocoa, xz

I have a damaged archive XZ compressed and tried to extract some files using hexdump unsuccessfully:

```
hexdump -C $myfile.xz  | grep 7zXZ # to find the possible headers
```

then I did the same to find the footer(s):

```
hexdump -C $myfile.xz  | grep ]YZ
```

Then I use dd to dump the bytes between the header and the footer

```
dd if=$myfile.xz  skip=329872480  bs=1 count=5710 of=$newFile.xz
```

(Header is one skipping at offset 329872480 and the footer is 5710 bites later, that are those nearby)

I try that several times at differents hoffset, and using the unarchiver.app (I'm on OSX) and looking at its temporary file I can read in clare the document inside, but anyway unarchiver and unxz told me that archive (the new archive dumped with dd) is not complete....
Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In addition, the file in question appear to be a "multi streamed" archive.. if I may say so..

Comment: Does `Archive Utility.app` even recognize `.xz` archives?  It doesn't under OS X 10.8.5 anyway.  I downloaded source code for `xz` and compiled/installed it on my system to deal with `xz` archives.

Comment: I'm on mavericks now, but Yosemite sure can decompress .txz file, and yes, XZ utils is installed in my System as you can read in my question (unxz). Anyway I have a corrupted archive to deal with, ...with some important file inside.. That 's what I try to solve here..

Comment: Ok Ok, maybe footer is not "]YZ" but only "YZ" (595a in Hex), but this way become hard. I need the lenght of the stream... but I don't know how. Reading here http://tukaani.org/xz/xz-file-format-1.0.4.txt "Stream Flag" and "Backward Size" can be usefull to find the real footer (+2 bytes?)...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://superuser.com , not stackoverflow.